# Using a Raspberry as on-boot auto media player from USB over HDMI to TV, changing files from network

Tags: hdmi, media-server, media

There's a TV where I work, and we show products videos to the clients, so I was wondering if we could connect a Raspberry to the TV, and change the files on the USB Drive from the network, over WIFI, so we don't bother clients turning off the tv and removing the usb drive to change the video files.

Thanks!

Edit: The idea is to attach the Raspberry to the TV over HDMI, and let it standing alone. The Raspberry should play h.264 files random from a usb drive, and I'm supposed to be able to delete, add, and modify files over wifi, from my mac at my office 100 mt away from the tv.

Comment: Could you update your question with more details about the actual equipment being used, how the equipment is connected, and how you are currently showing the product videos? The short answer is you can connect a Raspberry Pi to an HDMI television and you can display video. With my Raspberry Pi 3 I can watch and listen to YouTube videos after increasing the GPU memory to 256. Part of the question needs to be what is the format of the product video files and whether there is a player for that file format or not.

Comment: The videos are mostly h.264 mp4.
The idea is to connect the Raspberry over HDMI to the TV, and then somehow, change the files over wifi, delete videos, upload new videos, etc.
The videos are random, so I dont care a lot about choosing a specific video.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're thinking of it like a USB storage device.  Where the TV is reading video files directly from USB.

That's going to be a bit tough I would instead suggest attaching the Raspberry Pi to the TV via HDMI.  Then install Kodi and point it at the videos on the hard drive.  (Yes, they can be uploaded over the network).

Then you can either use a web interface or a smartphone app to select which videos play.  You can create a playlist and set it to repeat.

Comment: I think the video playing part should be easy, the "hard part" is the thum drive access over network, from my office away from the TV.
I'll give it a try tru SMB.
Thanks!

Comment: You can set Kodi to mount an existing SMB share, or you can just copy the files over to it (via SSH, or set up its own SMB or NFS share)